# Koa.js render angular html page

Tags: angularjs, node.js, koa, koa2

I was trying to use Koa.js instead of express for node.js.

In express we have used render function to fetch the html page.

I tried to access angular html page from Koa.js using the below code as below:

```
app.use(async function (ctx, next) {
  return send(ctx, 'views/index.html', { root: ''
})
.then(() => next()) })
```

But the above code displays the index page as it is without styles and the ng-view datas are not rendered

Also, I tried adding co-views as below

```
var views = require('co-views');
var render= views(__dirname + '/views', 
{ map: { html: 'swig' }});
```

But, I didnt get the result as expected. It also displays the page as mentioned above.

Please help to get the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have very specific requirements for serving static files, most of the time you can get away with `koa-static`:

```
import serve from 'koa-static'

// ...

app.use(serve(`${__dirname}/public`))
```

If you have more particular needs, you might need to edit your question.